# Why is my React Component Not Rendering HTML, but logs correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-component

I'm using Redux to store some API-called data, and in my attempt to render it to screen, I've encountered some issues. Basically, I'm using Redux and Fetch to store all the pulled [Products from the Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products) into a state(prop?) called "products", it's structure looks like this:

```
{ products:
  product1ID: {
    items: [
      0: {json data from Stripe Product API}
    ]
  },
  product2ID: {
    items: [
      0: {json data from Stripe Product API}
    ]
  },
  etc...
}
```

This is not the most effective structure, and will likely need to be refactored. However, that's not the issue at the moment, because I can, at least, return the data using `console.log()`. **The real issue is**, when an element is inside the `.forEach` / `.map` loop, I cannot render my component, or any HTML to the page. Here's my "ProductList" component, that breaks down the structure above:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ProductListItem from './Items/ProductListItem'
import selectProducts from '../../../_selectors/products.selector';


const ProductList = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Stripe Product List</h1> //This Prints to Screen
    {
      Object.entries(props.products).forEach(element => {
        return element[1].items.map((product) => {
          //console.log(product)  <-- this logs the json API data correctly! However, nothing prints to screen using HTML elements below!
          return <ProductListItem key={product.id} {...product} /> //This does not display!!! Why?
        })
      })
    }
  </div>
);


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    products: selectProducts(state.productsById)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductList);
```

And heres the ProductListItem, just in case you need it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductListItem = ({ id, name, metadata }) => (
  <Link to={`/memberships/${id}`} className="membership red">
    <div className="membership__price">
      <span className="membership__price_price-label">${metadata.price_start}</span>
      <span className="membership__price_mo-label">/mo</span>
    </div>
    <div className="membership__info">
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <p>{metadata.service_description}</p>
    </div>
  </Link>
);

export default ProductListItem;
```

So what gives? It logs the correct data, but won't output any HTML. I can't even get a `<p>` tag to return when I replace the `return <ProductListItem key={product.id} {...product} />` line with something simple, like: `return <p>test</p>`.

I'm fairly new to React and Redux. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within JSX you are attempting to return an array of React elements using the `Array#forEach` method.

The difference between [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and something like [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the returning value.

- The `Array.forEach()` method does not return a value, disregarding the values returned within its callback.
- The `Array.map()` method returns an array with the values returned from its callback.

---

## Solution

To fix your issue, you should replace [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
Object.entries(props.products).forEach
```

with the following:

```
Object.entries(props.products).map
```